# generating a Markov chain simulation using a transition matrix of specific size and with a given seed, using the mchmm library

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to generate a Markov simulation using a specific sequence as start, using the [mchmm](https://github.com/maximtrp/mchmm) library coded with scipy and numpy. I am not sure if I am using it correctly, since the library also has Viterbi and Baum-Welch algorithms in the context of Markov, which I am not familiar with.

To illustrate, I will continue with an example.

```
data = 'AABCABCBAAAACBCBACBABCABCBACBACBABABCBACBBCBBCBCBCBACBABABCBCBAAACABABCBBCBCBCBCBCBAABCBBCBCBCCCBABCBCBBABCBABCABCCABABCBABC'
a = mc.MarkovChain().from_data(data)
```

I want a markov simulation based on a 3 states transition matrix, starting with the last 3 characters in the sequence above *("ABC")*

```
start_sequence = data[-3:]
tfm3 = a.n_order_matrix(a.observed_p_matrix, order=3) #this is because  I want an order 3 transition matrix
ids, states = a.simulate(n=10, tf=tfm3, start=start_sequence)
```

this returns:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2552615/2308700615.py in <module>
----> 1 ids, states = a.simulate(n=10, tf=tfm3, start=start_sequence)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mchmm/_mc.py in simulate(self, n, tf, states, start, ret, seed)
    304             _start = np.random.randint(0, len(states))
    305         elif isinstance(start, str):
--> 306             _start = np.argwhere(states == start).item()
    307 
    308         # simulated sequence init

ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

I was expecting to get a sequence of 10 characters, starting with the string 'ABC' (data[-3:]), since I want to constraint the Markov simulation to start with the probabilities implied by that specific sequence, and following a Markov of order 3.

Any feedback?

Comment: good catch. yes, i accidentally copied the wrong string. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The states in the `MarkovChain` instance `a` are `'A'`, `'B'` and `'C'`.  When the `simulate` method is given a string for `state`, it expects it to be the name of one of the states, i.e. either `'A'`, `'B'` or `'C'`.  You get that error because `data[-3:]` is not one of the states.

For example, in the following I use `start='A'` in the call of `simulate()`, and it generates a sequence of 10 states, starting at `'A'`:

```
In [26]: data = 'AABCABCBAAAACBCBACBABCABCBACBACBABABCBACBBCBBCBCBCBACBABABCBCBA
    ...: AACABABCBBCBCBCBCBCBAABCBBCBCBCCCBABCBCBBABCBABCABCCABABCBABC'

In [27]: a = mc.MarkovChain().from_data(data)

In [28]: tfm3 = a.n_order_matrix(a.observed_p_matrix, order=3)

In [29]: ids, states = a.simulate(n=10, tf=tfm3, start='A')

In [30]: states
Out[30]: array(['A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'B'], dtype='<U1')
```

---

If you are trying to create a Markov chain where the states are sequences of three symbols (to add "history" that includes the previous two states), you could create a new input to `.from_data()` that consists of the length-3 overlapping subsequences of `data` (also known as the [3-grams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram)).  For example,

```
In [65]: data3 = [data[k:k+3] for k in range(len(data)-2)]

In [66]: data3[:4]
Out[66]: ['AAB', 'ABC', 'BCA', 'CAB']

In [67]: data3[-8:]
Out[67]: ['CAB', 'ABA', 'BAB', 'ABC', 'BCB', 'CBA', 'BAB', 'ABC']

In [68]: a = mc.MarkovChain().from_data(data3)
```

Take a look at the states of this Markov chain:

```
In [69]: a.states
Out[69]: 
array(['AAA', 'AAB', 'AAC', 'ABA', 'ABC', 'ACA', 'ACB', 'BAA', 'BAB',
       'BAC', 'BBA', 'BBC', 'BCA', 'BCB', 'BCC', 'CAB', 'CBA', 'CBB',
       'CBC', 'CCA', 'CCB', 'CCC'], dtype='<U3')
```

Simulate 10 transitions, starting with the last state in `data3`:

```
In [70]: ids, states = a.simulate(n=10, start=data3[-1])

In [71]: states
Out[71]: 
array(['ABC', 'BCA', 'CAB', 'ABC', 'BCB', 'CBC', 'BCB', 'CBA', 'BAA',
       'AAB'], dtype='<U3')
```

Compress the states to only include the final single character, so it is back in the form of the original `data` input:

```
In [72]: ''.join([state[-1] for state in states])
Out[72]: 'CABCBCBAAB'
```

Comment: Yes, tried that before, but that's not the solution I want. You are prob right but generating a Markov starting with the seed "*", "*" "A" is different to starting with a specific sequence before the "A" (like "CBA"). Maybe the code from the author is perfectly fine, and the library has some limitations. There is a "brute force" solution, which is to generate many sims (place the code in a loop, for example), and save the first one that has the "ABC" starting sequence. However, that would be very inefficient. I need to inspect the code more carefully and figure out where to mod efficiently.

Comment: What are the actual states of the Markov chain that you are trying to simulate?  In the one that you have created, the states are just `'A'`, `'B'` and `'C'`, so a "seed" of `"", "", "A"` doesn't make sense (to me, anyway).  Perhaps you need to modify the input to the `from_data` method to something like `['AAB', 'CAB', 'BCB', ...]` (i.e. break into length 3 subsequences), or `['AAB', 'ABC', 'BCA', 'CAB', ...]` (overlapping length 3 subsequences).

Comment: Exactly. Maybe in your example, 'AAB' is  state '1', 'CAB' is state '0', etc. something like that. What I don't get in the code is that you can specify starting states Optional[Union[np.ndarray, list]], but not sure how numeric "states" map to strings in the example

Comment: I updated my answer to include one way that you could include transitions among "states" that are three symbols long.

Comment: Excellent, that recreates what I intended to do. Cheers